# Converting movie primitives from NetLogo 5 to 6

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to convert the following procedure from NetLogo 5 to 6.

NL5 Procedure:

```
to make-movie
  user-message "Enter name ending with .mov"  
  let path user-new-file  
  if not is-string? path [ stop ]  
  reset movie-start  path 
  while [  ticks <= 300 ] [ run-model movie-grab-view ] 
  movie-close
end
```

My conversion to NL6:

```
to make-movie
  user-message "Enter name ending with .mov"  
  let path user-new-file
  if not is-string? path [ stop ]  
  reset vid:start-recorder path 
  while [  ticks <= 300 ] [ run-model vid:record-view ] 
  vid:save-recording path 
end
```

The system is flagging an error in my conversion on 'path' on the following line ... suggesting that a command is expected instead of the file-to-open as represented by 'path'

`reset vid:start-recorder path`

I have read through the [vid extension docs](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo//docs/vid.html#vid:start-recorder) ... as well as the transitions for the [movie primitives](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#removal-of-movie-prims), but just cannot figure out how to get around this.

Any suggestions, pointers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just forgot to update the `reset` to `vid:reset-recorder`, it's also from the vid extension.

`vid:start-recorder` doesnt take a path as input. You only need the path for `vid:save-recording`

In the [video extensions doc](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo//docs/vid.html#vid:save-recording) at the section for `vid:save-recording`, they say:

> Note that at present the recording will always be saved in the “mp4” format.

So you probably want so change the user message.
When I tried it with the following code the file extension was written automatically.

```
extensions[vid]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 10
end

to make-movie
  setup
  user-message "Enter name ending with .mov"  
  let path user-new-file
  if not is-string? path [ stop ]  
  vid:reset-recorder
  vid:start-recorder 
  while [  ticks <= 10 ] 
  [
    go vid:record-view
  ] 
  vid:save-recording path 
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Awesome, and indeed you were correct.  thanks a million.  I didn't forget about converting 'reset' to the new format.  I just was unaware of it (very new to NetLogo, and the vid extension).  Thanks again.  You are a star.